# How to structure my Core Data entities?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to store some information within Core Data which will achieve this structure.

#### Entity

> Entity: Recipe
>
> Attribute: Name (string), Ingredient (transformable), Cost (transformable)

#### Sample Data

> Name = Pancake
>
> Ingredient = [Egg, Flour, Milk]
>
> Cost = [2.00,1.00,3.00,10.00,5.00]

The aim is to be able to store multiple recipes and for each of them, the array size for ingredient and cost will be different. Meanwhile in the Table View, it will list all of the ingredients, however will only present the last known Cost, i.e. 5.00 in this example. There will be functionality to add more ingredients or cost for a single recipe.

Initially, I've tried to approach this using the Transformable attribute to store the data for Ingredient and Cost. However, after some reading, it seems like making use of relationships could be a better option. Can someone kindly provide an explanation on how I should restructure my data to achieve the above using relationships (or perhaps another kind of solution)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using any transformable here. I don't totally understand your description but here is the general approach to use. Sounds like you need a Recipe class, a Ingredients class and a Cost class

`Recipe` has a `name` property, an `ingredients` relationship and a `costs` relationship.

`Ingredient` has a `name` property, a `quantity` property and a `recipe` relationship.

`Cost` has a `total` property, a `date` property and a `recipe` relationship.